# jdbc source and spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark

I've been using spark structured streaming, and quite happy with it. I'm currently performing an ETL type activity. I have a table based in PostgreSQL which contains metadata type information, that I'm looking to merge with the streaming data frame.

```
metadataDf = spark \
    .read \
    .jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, \
        table = query,
        properties = connectionProperties) 

streamDF = spark \
    .readStream \
    .option("maxFilesPerTrigger",10) \
    .option("latestFirst",True) \
    .schema(sensorSchema) \
    .json(sensorPath)

joined_metadata = streamDF \
    .join(metadataDf,["uid"],"left")

write_query = joined_metadata \
    .writeStream \
    .trigger(processingTime=arbitarytime) \
    .format("json") \
    .option("checkpointLocation",chkploc) \
    .option("path",write_path) \
    .start()
```

The metadata table on postgresql can get updated once every couple of days. I was wondering, do I need to accommodate the refresh of the table on spark with some kind of while loop. Or does spark's lazy eval takes care of that particular scenario.

Thanks

Comment: what was the solution you finally went with ?

Comment: I went for as is, the answer describes why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark will take care of it as long as the program is running. If you don't specify a trigger interval Spark will process this stream continuously (each batch starts once the last has finished)

To specify a trigger interval see `df.trigger()` [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/streaming.html#DataStreamWriter.trigger) and [in the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter)

:)

Comment: sorry, I have a write query which has trigger() set. I've updated the question. So, in this case just to confirm will the write query will get a new batch of table from the jdbc connection?

Comment: Yes, it's going to try and read/write from the `jdbc` connection every time. I would add some conditional logical to only perform the join & write if your `streamDF.count() > 0`